# Is there an easy way to nest fields with jackson json annotations in java?

Tags: java, jackson

I am looking for a way to do something like this without being forced to have to create a new separate object for the "content" value which would just hold a string inside the object.

```
@JsonNestedProperty("value.content")
String value = "my_value";
```

```
{
  "value": {
    "content": "my_value"
  }
}
```

Currently making new objects in order to nest fields

```
@JsonProperty("value")
MyContent value;

class MyContent {
  @JsonProperty("content")
  String content = "my_value";
}
```

Comment: Maybe ```Map<String, String> value = map.of("content", "my_value");```?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ObjectWriter#withRootName`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#withRootName-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyName-) method to wrap a distinct `Content` object with a string as a new rootname in the serialization process like the example below:

```
public class Content {

    @JsonProperty("content")
    String content = "my_value";
}

Content content = new Content();
//wrapping the Content obj with new rootname "value"
//it prints {"value":{"content":"my_value"}}
System.out.println(mapper.writer()
                         .withRootName("value")
                         .writeValueAsString(content));
```

If you want to wrap all `Content` objects with the same rootname you can annotate the `Content` class with the [`JsonRootName`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html) annotation and use the [`ObjectWriter#with`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#with-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature-) method with the [`SerializationFeature#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE) serialization feature like the example below:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "value")
public class Content {

    @JsonProperty("content")
    String content = "my_value";
}

Content content = new Content();
//it prints {"value":{"content":"my_value"}}
System.out.println(mapper.writer()
                         .with(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
                         .writeValueAsString(content));
```